# Ways to compare sql database schema programmaticall in C# .net or .netcore

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

There exists a way to compare two SQL databases and generate the change scripts and even deploy the changes to the remote database. I have seen somewhere in one of the blogs where the author describe the way to programmatically iterate all the objects of the database and allow you to control the comparison. I am quite unable to find that link but if anyone knows the snippet of the code or the nugget packages to begin with please post here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.compare.schemacomparison?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1 There is also another way - SSDT deployment contributor (google for Ed Elliott articles for contributors and SSDT overall). Depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to**

> Visual Studio --> Tools --> Sql Server --> New Data Comparison | New Schema Comparison

Comment: You cannot select source schema as non-sqlproj

Answer (score 0):

You will use the same libraries like for deploying a dacpac project: `DacServices` utility class in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac`.

You will use 'Extract' method to create a dacpac files for your source database and then use 'Deploy' or 'GenerateDeployScript'.

Comment: How can I begin the comparison of two databases?

Comment: Extract copy schema of your target db to a "dacpac" file , deploy compares schema from "dacpac" to another database and generates change script.